# jquery ajaxStart/ajaxStop not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have very simple code that i making partial postback by jquery and i use ajaxStart/ajaxStop for doing some work. but it is not working. i just could not understand why it is not working.
here is my code

```
$("#imgHolder").ajaxStart(function () {
 $('div#content').block({
          message: '<table><tr><td><img  src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0"/></td><td><h3>Processing...</h3></td></tr><table>',
        css: { border: '1px solid #a00' }
        });
    $('#imgHolder').empty();
    $("#btnPrint").hide();
    });

  $("#imgHolder").ajaxStop(function () {
  $("#btnPrint").show();
  $('div#content').unblock();
 });  



$(document).ready(function () {
 $.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "UPSLabelFormUK.aspx/ProcessInfo",
  data: JSON.stringify(DTO),
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  dataType: "json",
  success: function (data) {
  if (data.d[0].Message == "SUCCESS") {
  //alert(data.d[0].TrackNumber);
  ///alert(data.d[0].LabelImagePath);
  var _images = [data.d[0].LabelImagePath];
  $.each(_images, function (e) {
    $(new Image()).load(function () {
    $('#imgHolder').html("<img src='" + data.d[0].LabelImagePath + "' width='310' height='402' border=0/>");
  }).attr('src', this);
 });
}
 } ,
  error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
  alert(textStatus);
  }
 });
 });
```

i just dont not understand why my above ajaxstart/ajaxstop did not work. please help me to understand why was wrong in my code.

but my  ajaxstart/ajaxstop started working when i change the code a bit like

```
        $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
            $('div#content').block({
                message: '<table><tr><td><img  src="../images/ajax-loader.gif" border="0"/></td><td><h3>Processing...</h3></td></tr><table>',
                css: { border: '1px solid #a00' }
            });

            $('#imgHolder').empty();
            $("#btnPrint").hide();
        });


        $(document).ajaxStop(function () {
            $("#btnPrint").show();
            $('div#content').unblock();
        });
```

the only change is `$(document).ajaxStop(function () {` instaed of

```
$("#imgHolder").ajaxStart(function () {
```

so please explain why my above ajaxStart/ajaxStop code did not work. thanks

Answer (score 10, accepted):

> Given the fact that ajaxStart is only called if there are no other
>   ajax requests in progress, it makes is useless if you want to use it
>   as an AJAX loader indicator.

have u tried with ( tell me is it working or not)

```
jQuery(document).ajaxStart(function(){
alert("it begins");
})
```

Comment: ur code will work but when use the code like $("#imgHolder").ajaxStart(function () { i mean bind with div then it is not working.plzz explain why?

Answer (score 8):

> As of jQuery 1.8, the .ajaxStop() method should only be attached to document.

from jquery api web page of "ajaxStop". You can check it [here](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxStop/).

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$("#loading").bind({
   ajaxStart: function() { $(this).show(); },
   ajaxStop: function() { $(this).hide(); }
});
```

Essentially binding your loadingAnimationElement to the globally fired ajaxStart and ajaxStop events. Only shows up when you intend it to.

When jQuery is not performing any Ajax requests and a new request is initiated, it fires an ajaxStart event. If other requests begin before this first one ends, those new requests do not cause a new ajaxStart event. The ajaxStop event is triggered when the last pending Ajax request is completed and jQuery is no longer performing any network activity.

Comment: While this answer is probably correct and useful, it is preferred if you include some explanation along with it to explain how it helps to solve the problem. This becomes especially useful in the future, if there is a change (possibly unrelated) that causes it to stop working and users need to understand how it once worked.

Answer (score 0):

Try this sample code:-

```
 var $loading = $('#div_Loader').hide();
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {  
         $loading.show();
    })
    .ajaxStop(function () {
        setTimeout(function () {                 
            $loading.hide();
        }, 1000);                                  
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

This combination works fine. Thanks to user **@brroshan**

**JS of Master page**

```
<script language="JavaScript" type="text/javascript">

$(document).ajaxStart(function () {
     $("#loading").show();
});

$(function () {

// Some other code

// The end of this code block

$("#loading").hide();

$("#loading").bind({
         ajaxStart: function () { $(this).show(); },
         ajaxStop: function () { $(this).hide(); }
     });

});

</script>
```

**html of Master page**

```
<div id="loading" class="display: none;">
    <h2>Loading...</h2>
</div>
```